# Error in OpenNLP package - dataframe coercing

Tags: r, dataframe, opennlp, coerce

I am trying to run a basic sentence annotation function and I keep running into the same error.

The code I tried to use is:

```
 s <- as.String(cleandata) #cleandata is my data.It is a character class.
 sent_ann <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
 a2 <- annotate(s,sent_ann)
```

The above code keeps generating the error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "c("Simple_Sent_Token_Annotator", "Annotator")" to a data.frame
```

What do I do ?

Answer (score 5):

I was getting your same error, doing exactly the same.
Then I restarted R-studio, I loaded the libraries

```
library(NLP);
library(tm);
library(openNLP);
library(openNLPmodels.en);
```

and I could execute the statement successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. In my case the tidyverse library was overwriting the annotate function from NLP. This should work:

```
library(NLP);
library(openNLP);
```